# Dynamically naming an instance of a class?

Tags: java, class, constructor, joptionpane

Just a really quick question about something small. The following is part of a programming assignment for my programming 2 class. It focuses on inheritance and multiple classes. I've answered the question but want to consolidate the classes into a main function and actually build something rather than just submitting the bare minimum.

My question is the section of code below. The user runs the program, is presented with a dialog asking him as to what he's like to add (a CD or a Movie, they're both separate classes).

What I would like though, is for the user to actually name the specific instance of the class while the program is running. So, the user will click Movie for example, be prompt to enter a name and then next line to use the constructor in the movie class to create a new instance class with the name the user entered? Is this possible? I tried using a simple string x = JOptionpane and then naming the class x also, but it didn't work. I'm thinking there might be some method that will refer to the string? like contents.x maybe?

thanks in advance!

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class Main 
{

    public static void main (String args [])
    {
    Object[] options = {"Movie",
                "CD",
                "Cancel"};
            int n = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Would you like to add an item?","Product",
                        JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION,
                            JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
                                null,
                                    options,
                                        options[2]);

    switch(n)
    {
    case 0: 
    String moviet = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Title:");
    int movieID = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("ID:"));
    Movie moviett = new Movie(moviet, movieID);


    }


    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's not too far beyond your class' content, you could use a [`Map<String, Media>`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)<sup>1</sup> to store instances identified by a runtime-specified string.

```
Map<String, Media> instances = new HashMap<>();
// snip...
String moviet = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Title:");
int movieID = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("ID:"));
Movie moviett = new Movie(moviet, movieID);
instances.put("some user-provided string", moviett);
```

---

<sub><sup>1</sup>Assuming that `Movie` and `CD` both extend/implement `Media`.</sub>

Comment: GMTA, and you beat me to the punch! 1+

Comment: My nipples explode with delight

Comment: This is a bit over my head, but I'll look into it. Thank you for the speedy reply. Time to get googling!

Answer (score 2):

Java doesn't work this way, and in fact variable names are much less important than you think and almost don't exist in compiled code. Instead how about using Strings to set a field of the Movie class, perhaps a String field called "name". If you want to retrieve a class instance based on a String, consider using a Map such as a HashMap.